# Generating mleap bundle from my TensorFlow program

Tags: serialization, tensorflow, mleap

I have a TensorFlow model which I am trying to serialise into a MLeap bundle, so that I can use MLeap based predictor to score. But I could not find any API to do so from my TensorFlow code.

The MLeap documentation talks about freezing the TF graph using freeze_graph api of TF, which I did, but post this step I see no instruction on how to get the bundle generated from the frozen model pb file. Could some one help me find an answer to this?